# a matter/the matter of/for debate /a debate

Tags: articles

The problem is this.

1 **A matter of something** means a question of something.

This is a matter of time. = This is a question of time.

This is a matter of debate. = Something can be solved or negotiated by means of debate.

2 **The matter of something** means the topic of something.

The matter of this book is English.

My first question:
Can "a matter of something" mean "a topic of something" rather than "a question of something"? For example:

**There are many things to discuss, English can be a matter of debate.** (if I mean that it's only one of many topics which can be discussed, it is OK to say "a matter of"? I can see that "English is a matter of debate" can mean something far-fetched as if we can stipulate some norms of English by debating, it's not what I mean. Or should it be "**There are many things to discuss, English can be THE matter of debate.**)?

My next question is about the use of articles with **debate**.

What's the difference between

> "A matter of debate" VS. "A matter of a debate"
>
> "The matter of debate" VS. "The matter of a debate"
>
> "The matter for debate" VS. "The matter for a debate"

Comment: The idiom is: a matter for debate [requires being debated] or of debate [already exists].

Answer (score 1):

"Matter" is not actually perfectly interchangeable with "subject" or "topic". "Matter" can be used as a very generic way of referring to any situation, event, topic, subject, circumstance, concern, etc., but it's not an exact synonym for any of these words. It's used here in the same way as "thing"--as a high-level abstraction. So you might say "We discussed academic matters" or "academic things" instead of "academic subjects", but you would not say "the matter of this book is academic" or "the thing of this book is academic" instead of "the subject of this book is academic".

"Matter of" is almost always used in the set phrase "a matter of". "Matter" in the sense of "subject" is usually used with "in": "the matter in debate", "the matter in question", etc. Again, "matter" here behaves the same as the abstraction "thing".

Regarding your second question:

"It's a matter of debate": means there may be several opinions about it and the topic is not settled.

"It's a matter of a debate": can mean something like "it's a question of holding a debate about it" or "a debate should be held about it".

"The matter of debate": sounds awkward. Should be "the matter in debate".

"The matter of a debate": very awkward. I can't think of when it would be used, if ever.

"The matter for debate": there is an idiom "a matter for debate", and it's always used with the indefinite article, never with "the". For example, "Human rights are not a matter for debate."

"The matter for a debate": very awkward. I can't think of when it would be used, if ever.